# Javascript - If statement not working as planned

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested, operator-keyword

I have an issue with one line of code which doesn't seem to be doing as expected:

```
if (name === contacts[i].firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        return contacts[i][prop];
```

It should check if name matches the firstName of the object and if the object has a property of prop - returning the property if both are true. However, this bit of code seems to be skipped over when running test as each result gives me the answer of "No such contact".

```js
// Setup
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  
for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length ; i++){
  
  if (name === contacts[i].firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    return contacts[i][prop];
  }else if (name !== contacts[i]["firstName"]){
    return "No such contact"
  }else if (prop !== contacts[i]["prop"])
    return "No such property";
  } 

  // Only change code above this line
}
const search = lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");

console.log(search);
```

There is a solution below which uses a nested IF statement but I want to know why my initial way of trying to solve it doesn't work.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}
```

The problem in full can be accessed here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup

Comment: "*this bit of code seems to be skipped over*" - no, it's not getting skipped over. But your first snippet only checks the first profile, and `return`s from the function in the first iteration of the loop, never looking at the other profiles. `lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");` might work, but `lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes");` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Why would it not go through the rest of the iterations? Since each iteration is based on the i value from the for loop, I'm not sure why it would stop at 1. Also `lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");` doesn't seem to return anything either.

Comment: `return` exits the loop and the function, returning the specified value to the caller immediately not running any remaining code. You can remove both `else` clauses and handle them seperately as you've done in your second example.

Comment: @pilchard - Thank for the reply, I believe @Bergi said something similar - from my understanding the return should only pull us out of the loop if both the IF conditions have been met in which case in which case `return contacts[i][prop];` should print on the console the property called - Which is my end goal. However, this is not the case, for some reason it doesn't seem to return the 'prop' .

Comment: If either is not met you move on to the `else if` clauses one of which will definitely `return` because they are the inverse conditions that you already tested (and at least one of which failed).

Comment: @DCoderT Ah, I didn't spot the second bug. `else if (prop !== contacts[i]["prop"]) {` could be just `else {`, since `prop` is always a string and `contacts[i].prop` is always `undefined` (none of your `contacts` have a property named `"prop"`) so the `if` always matches.

Comment: @pilchard - Gotcha - that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Setup
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  const contact = contacts.find(({ firstName }) => firstName === name);
  if (!contact) {
    return "No such contact"
  }
  if (!contact[prop]) {
    return "No such property";
  }
  return contact[prop];
}

const search = lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");

console.log(search);
```

Comment: OP already has a working solution. They're looking for an explanation of why their first snippet doesn't work.